# How to make a div 500% but still center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image like the b[image]

Im trying to achieve an infinite line at the bottom so no matter what screen the line fills the width of the screen.

I have cropped my image and set it to the bottom of a div so i can use a boarder but when i use

```
.row2{
  position: absolute;
  width:500%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The div just seems to stretch 510% to the right rather than 250 to the left and 250 to the right and keeping my image the same size (it also moves my image to the center of the div so way off screen)

This is my html :

```
 <div class="row row2">
   <div class="col-xl-12 hscentertext" style="">
      <img src="assets/img/25k.png" class="img-fluid center-block text-xl-center" alt="Responsive image"> 
    </div>
 </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the div has `position: absolute;` so it will base on `left` and `right`, try to use `left: 50%` may keep your div center

Comment: That is because the `row` class in bootstrap gives margin on the either side by default, it does not spread to 100% width. Try using `row-fluid` class instead

Comment: Why do you need 500%, it's absolutely nonsense. "infinite line" you can achieve also with 100%, with fluid container.

Comment: The problem is it's inside <div class="jumbotron">

Comment: Why is it a problem if it's inside a .jumbotron? Can't you make that 100% wide as well. I think you should rework html structure if you got to the point where you HAVE to use position: absolute; for this. Can you set up a fiddle with the whole page structure?

Comment: Hello, this is twice i see this image and your (similar) question reworded. Could you share that image too cause it is not clear what you screens shows. Is that the image itself or image within a container and margins/paddings around it ? to draw a line asides should not be a big deal :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `position: absolute;` for this:

```css
html, body {
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row2 {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.row2 .hscentertext {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row2">
  <div class="col-xl-12 hscentertext" style="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="img-fluid center-block text-xl-center" alt="Responsive image"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Unless you have other reasons to use `position: absolute;` in which case can center it with transforms:

```
.selector {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

By using the `translateX(-50%);` trick the element will always be centered, regardless of it's width.

Comment: No problem, but I'm going to repeat what I said in the OP comments. If you got to the point where you're using position: absolute; for something like this, you probably should rework your html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide the image, i remade one :[image: edges cut off] cutting off edges for the snippet below:

```css
.myimg {
  background-color: #D52226;
/* draw the line behind*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 3px, white 3px, white 5px, transparent 5px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row2">
  <div class="col-xl-12 hscentertext myimg" style="">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf9Cy.jpg" class="img-fluid center-block text-xl-center" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
</div>
```

The width of that image used can be reduced to the text it holds.
[image]

The line can be drawn on the background of the container . 
It can be a gradient or few pixel dot repeated over a background-color.
display:flex can help too to work from a translucide png, which allows background to be modify: [example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/yVYgoV).

```css
.myimg {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #D52226;
}
.myimg:before,
.myimg:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 3px, white 3px, white 5px, transparent 5px);
}
.myimg:hover {
  background-color: #4195BE
}
```

```html
<div class="row row2">
  <div class="col-xl-12 hscentertext myimg">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/37doI.png" class="img-fluid center-block text-xl-center" alt="Responsive image">
  </div>
</div>
```